# Weak Equivalence of Pullbacks

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

This is a modification of the question I previously asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1829538/proving-that-a-map-is-a-weak-homotopy-equivalence).

Consider the category of pointed topological spaces $C$. Suppose objects $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h \in C$. Suppose we have two pullback squares where all the morphisms are serre fibrations $$\begin{array}& &a&\to &b\\
&\downarrow & &\downarrow \\
&c &\to &d\end{array}$$
$$\begin{array}& &e&\to &f\\
&\downarrow & &\downarrow \\
&g &\to &h\end{array}$$
and maps $f_{ae}:a \to e,f_{bf}:b \to f, f_{cg}:c \to g,f_{dh}:d \to h$ satisfying the obvious commutativity conditions. Then I want to show that if  $f_{bf}, f_{cg},f_{dh}$ are weak homotopy equivalence then so is $f_{ae}$.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83644/do-homotopy-pullbacks-preserve-weak-homotopy-equivalences/135275#135275  ?